# Status: Failed -Test Failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection / docker-oracle / MAC m1 ErrorI have a question

Tags: oracle, docker

I am currently using oracle 11g using docker.

The image is jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g.

Previously, I connected to sql developer and dbeaver and used it well.

2-3 days ago, suddenly I can't connect and

Both sql and dbeaver error message is

Status: Failed -Test Failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=/DJQ/0BASUOpP2bmPQF+LQ==)

Rebooted the listener, rebooted the PC and docker,

deleting the docker container, deleting and reinstalling the images, and even checking the sqlplus connection inside the container.

When I first encountered this situation, when I deleted the container and recreated it and ran it, it worked well for one day, but then it didn't work, and it hasn't worked since then.

I also turned off the firewall on my MAC,

Just in case, I pinged the docker internal IP and it didn't go in.

I'm asking because I can't find an answer even if I search for it.

and I'm using mac M1 sonova version of OS.

After running colima in iterm, I login to docker, run docker container, and try to connect to sql.

```
traceroute 172.17.0.2
traceroute to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.042 ms  0.677 ms  0.532 ms
 2  * 1.220.247.73 (1.220.247.73)  6.970 ms  3.328 ms
 3   *
```

```
>  traceroute 172.17.0.2
traceroute to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.042 ms  0.677 ms  0.532 ms
 2  * 1.220.247.73 (1.220.247.73)  6.970 ms  3.328 ms
 3   *
❯ docker exec -it f3f97467c2d9 /bin/bash

root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = f3f97467c2d9)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = f3f97467c2d9)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

```
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  f3f97467c2d9
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# docker network inspect bridge
bash: docker: command not found
```

```
❯ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg                 en7
default            192.168.0.1        UGScIg                en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#22            UCS                   en7      !
169.254            link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0          link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0          link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0.1        58:86:94:45:ab:6c  UHLWIir               en0   1192
192.168.0.1/32     link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0.1        70:5d:cc:89:fb:86  UHLWIir               en7   1197
192.168.0.2        7a:d2:47:3b:e1:db  UHLWI                 en0    833
192.168.0.6/32     link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0.13       f6:58:dc:37:c2:59  UHLWI                 en0   1019
192.168.0.16       aa:fb:4d:aa:d0:52  UHLWIi                en0     45
192.168.0.29       c8:89:f3:ea:52:fe  UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.29       link#22            UHRLWI                en7      !
192.168.0.41       f8:32:e4:6e:24:b1  UHLWI                 en7    863
192.168.0.44       9e:4:88:a8:ee:21   UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.46       24:f5:aa:e3:74:17  UHLWI                 en0   1048
192.168.0.53       24:f5:aa:ad:61:fd  UHLWIi                en7    666
192.168.0.237      link#15            UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.243      ee:92:a0:b4:c2:36  UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.244/32   link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.0.250      e2:f1:36:56:16:8c  UHLWI                 en0     42
192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en0      !
192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en7      !
224.0.0/4          link#22            UmCS                  en7      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCSI                 en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en7
255.255.255.255/32 link#22            UCS                   en7      
 

 

>  traceroute 172.17.0.2
traceroute to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.042 ms  0.677 ms  0.532 ms
 2  * 1.220.247.73 (1.220.247.73)  6.970 ms  3.328 ms
 3   *
❯ docker exec -it f3f97467c2d9 /bin/bash

root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = f3f97467c2d9)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = f3f97467c2d9)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  f3f97467c2d9
root@f3f97467c2d9:/# docker network inspect bridge
bash: docker: command not found
❯ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg                 en7
default            192.168.0.1        UGScIg                en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#22            UCS                   en7      !
169.254            link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0          link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0          link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0.1        58:86:94:45:ab:6c  UHLWIir               en0   1192
192.168.0.1/32     link#15            UCSI                  en0      !
192.168.0.1        70:5d:cc:89:fb:86  UHLWIir               en7   1197
192.168.0.2        7a:d2:47:3b:e1:db  UHLWI                 en0    833
192.168.0.6/32     link#22            UCS                   en7      !
192.168.0.13       f6:58:dc:37:c2:59  UHLWI                 en0   1019
192.168.0.16       aa:fb:4d:aa:d0:52  UHLWIi                en0     45
192.168.0.29       c8:89:f3:ea:52:fe  UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.29       link#22            UHRLWI                en7      !
192.168.0.41       f8:32:e4:6e:24:b1  UHLWI                 en7    863
192.168.0.44       9e:4:88:a8:ee:21   UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.46       24:f5:aa:e3:74:17  UHLWI                 en0   1048
192.168.0.53       24:f5:aa:ad:61:fd  UHLWIi                en7    666
192.168.0.237      link#15            UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.243      ee:92:a0:b4:c2:36  UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.0.244/32   link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.0.250      e2:f1:36:56:16:8c  UHLWI                 en0     42
192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en0      !
192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en7      !
224.0.0/4          link#22            UmCS                  en7      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCSI                 en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en7
255.255.255.255/32 link#22            UCS                   en7      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCSI                  en0      !

❯ docker logs f3f97467c2d9

ls: cannot access /u01/app/oracle/oradata: No such file or directory
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Setting up:
processes=500
sessions=555
transactions=610
If you want to use different parameters set processes, sessions, transactions env variables and consider this formula:
processes=x
sessions=x*1.1+5
transactions=sessions*1.1

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
-------------------------------------------------
This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express
Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that
will be used for database accounts.  Press <Enter> to accept the defaults.
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:
Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:
Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully.
Database initialized. Please visit http://#containeer:8080/apex to proceed with configuration
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance is already started

Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)
found files in /u01/app/oracle/oradata Using them instead of initial database
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.

Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)
```

```
❯ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
f64dbd9c8662   bridge    bridge    local
bf969278eafc   host      host      local
8bd6a228426c   none      null      local

    ~ ································································································ at 09:57:03 AM 
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND             CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
f3f97467c2d9   jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g   "/entrypoint.sh "   13 hours ago   Up 43 minutes   0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, :::1521->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->8080/tcp, :::9000->8080/tcp   oracle_test
```

```
❯ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f64dbd9c866234bd839a9186fb4e6f1fed5ba44f1d3aad8b5fa655bde43ec66f",
        "Created": "2024-01-09T00:03:29.47448243Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "f3f97467c2d91e47c20dfafa5c792415e3ff88c9e07891166caa9e556bc81d95": {
                "Name": "oracle_test",
                "EndpointID": "32dd002a0e72585d45e79af1bd9bf4f196ed3e77b84b8782b75c8ac2f14157b0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

1. uninstall and reinstall docker
2. delete docker image, delete container and reconfigure
3. check listener ora file
4. turn off macbook firewall